# How to preselect options within a multi or single mat-select that relies on an Input() value?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have created this reusable select search component. This component can have preselected items. If the component is passed an array of preselected options then it should preselect them.

Currently, when I pass an item to preselect it correctly adds it to the form control, however it does not display correctly.

I have another Input() called `extractValue` where the user can pass the key value that should be displayed for the options.

I have tried `compareWith` function to pull the display value. This compareWith function runs BEFORE any Inputs() are fully loaded. So the `extractValue` is undefined. If I hard code this value it still doesn't seem to solve my issue.

Why does the form control set values not reflect in the UI?

Here is my code ---> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-multi-with-formcontrol-klabfl?file=app/select-search-dropdown.component.html

Answer (score 1):

Found the cause of your `compareWith` function, it was not able to get the `extractValue` as the scope of `this` in your function was of `mat-select` and your actual value of extractValue was present in your `this` of main component.

I didn't find anything, which will allow us to pass the scope of your parent component. But as a workaround, you can do the following:

1. Pass the extractValue in your selectSearchForm.
2. Then, access it using: `this._parentFormGroup.value.extractValue;` and make changes accordingly in your `compareFn`.

Below are the code changes and working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-multi-with-formcontrol-egkr7n?file=app/select-search-dropdown.component.ts)

```
private _setUpFormControls(
    validators?: ISelectSearchValidators[],
    selected?: any,
    setInitialValue?: boolean,
    multiple?: boolean
  ): void {
    debugger;
    this.selectSearchForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      SelectControl: [
        this._setInitialValue(selected, setInitialValue, multiple),
        this._getValidatorFns(validators)
      ],
      SearchControl: [""],
      extractValue: this.extractValue
    }); 
  }

compareFn(optionOne: any, optionTwo: any): boolean {
    const extractValue = this._parentFormGroup.value.extractValue;
    if (typeof optionOne === "string" && typeof optionTwo === "string") {
      return optionOne === optionTwo;
    } else if (!!optionOne[extractValue] && !!optionTwo[extractValue]) {
      return optionOne[extractValue] === optionTwo[extractValue];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! It appears that this is only working because it cannot find _parentFormGroup so this function isn't really doing anything. I switched the logic though to check if the optionOne and optionTwo objects are the same with underscore. If you edit your answer to use that instead I'll accept it. The preselected item didn't seem to work for the single select but it did work for the multi select.